# Most efficient way to loop through 10 character string in java?

Tags: java, string, performance, loops, sha256

I have seen a lot of different ways to do this but due to lack of experience in this area I'm not sure which is best. My program saves a lot of time the more efficient it is so I've come to you guys to ask.

All I need is a loop to hit every possible combination for a 10 character string in java involving: 
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789

So from aaaaaaaaaa to AAAAAAAAAA to 9999999999 using all the character combinations above.

Also mini-question (not necessary but please comment if you can help), what language would be quickest to write a database of Sha-256 hashes. In java I'm getting 1.5 million hashes a second on my current computer, but when I write them all to a text file it slows to 200k a second. Would a light weight scripting language like Python be quicker or is there any way to legally buy more computational power to run my programs?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sure. Let's help you build a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). That doesn't sound sketchy in the slightest.

Comment: My friend has a small time bitcoin gambling website and he is currently just using a random 10-char secret encrypted with sha-256. I'm just wondering if it's theoretically possible to map out a fraction of these and then refresh the page until a hash matches. Otherwise is it worth the effort of adding an individual salt to make it impossible to brute force?

Comment: @Ceelos I saw a presentation where someone rented an amazon or google or some higher end company server to help compute hashes at an insane rate, not sure if this is a commercial thing or if he worked for them.

Comment: If you want to brute force hashes, you should buy a quantum computer and have a look at [Grover's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) which would reduce the security of SHA-256 to 128 bits. If a quantum computer is not an option you could parallelize hashing on the GPU with OpenCL or CUDA but there is no way around testing all possible combinations.

Comment: @Palle haha that is way out of budget and that Algorithm is over my head. I found this calculator online (http://calc.opensecurityresearch.com/) it says 10,000 years to crack his mixalpha-numeric 10char secret but what if someone has a botnet and uses it's power against the website hashes, is this still impossible? I know I'm sounding sketchy af, but I'm trying to think from a hackers perspective because I am investing quite a bit into this project.

Comment: Ok look, where is this password stored? in a database? What is the database for the password? How many user's passwords are in this database? Brute force generally works through keywords or a gimme that you know of. If it is a random character set then ok you are good with hashing but if the database contains more than one password someone else with an easy password like 12345 will be found and therefore with the help of rainbow tables your password is in the open. Which is why we salt our passwords now.